# Why can't I upload this Arduino program?

Tags: windows, upload, arduino, usb, bootloader

Recently I have taken an introduction course for electronics and I have already learned plenty of programming. I was starting to learn about the Arduino. For some reason, whenever I try to upload a program, it speeds through it, and then gets stuck at the end of the bar. Then, after like 30 seconds, this error is given:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
[...]
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa1
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Note*: It won't even let me burn a new bootloader because it throws this error:

```
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
Error while burning bootloader.
```

Please respond quickly with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: The arduino code needs to identify a USB port as a virtual COM port.  It looks like the COM port has not been set up on your computer.  What operating system are you using, and how did you identify the USB port it is connected too?

Comment: You need a programmer in order to burn the bootloader.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the [getting started (Windows)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows) page?

Comment: A better site would be http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are so many different types of Arduinos, including counterfeits, clones, and competing products.  You should say which one you have and provide a link to where you bought it from.  You should also say what version of the software you have, and enable verbose upload in the preferences window.  You should also give information about what serial ports are on your computer and which one you selected in the Ports menu, and what board you selected in the software.

Answer (score 0):

Your device is not recognized by your computer. You need to install the proper drivers for the USB chip on your Arduino. Is it an FTDI chip? Or a CP2102? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1) If you run Arduino IDE under Windows, you have to install the USB driver (not necessary on Apple and Linux operating systems)

2) You must insert the Arduino USB cable in a USB slot first, and then start the IDE.

3) Check if you have selected the right model of Arduino (Tools/Board), and the proper COM (USB) slot (Tools/Port)